# Need sample 3D and multi-layer shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, data

I've been given a task to write a GIS (Shapefile .shp) rendering application.

The document and shapefile technical specification states that 3D shapefiles exist. The document also mentions that a single shapefile can have multiple layers, although the technical specification does not describe this.

I was not given sample files for either of these cases so I can't do anything. I've been looking all over google, but I cannot find any sample 3D or multi-layered shapefiles. Does anyone have, or know where I can find such files?

Comment: I'm not sure about the meaning of the "multiple layers" part - needs more context. Shapefiles with Z are pretty standard though. You can start with https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/autotest/ogr/data/multipointz_without_m.shp or more generally use GDAL to do the conversion / creation as needed.

Comment: Thanks for that link. It's only two dots but it's something. I don't really have to time to run the 3D aspect to completion anyway, but I'll look it to more later out of my own interesting. I'll leave the multi-layer part alone since its existence seems questionable. Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shapefiles with Z are pretty standard. You can start with github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/autotest/ogr/data for a range of simple test cases, or more generally use GDAL to do the conversion / creation as needed.

If you want to find examples of more complex examples, we have some in the [spatialite tests](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/dir?name=test/shp) - those are some "more interesting" test cases, with UTF-8 names, different projections and Z values. Another interesting set (larger variation over a consistent area) is the [GRASS Book set](https://grassbook.org/datasets/datasets-3rd-edition/).

I'm not sure about the meaning of the "multiple layers" part - that needs more context.